# jQuery Mobile on iPad: HTML5 video keeps playing after transition

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, video, jquery-mobile

On page 1 I have

```
<video width="100%" src="spacetime.m4v" controls></video>
```

to play a video. This all works nicely, however, when a user presses a button in the

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <a href="twinparadox.php">Page 2</a>
</div>
```

which is linked to another document, the video keeps playing while we transition smoothly to this other document.

Is there a way to stop the video in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You could hook into one of the **[jqMobile page events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html)** and manually `.pause()` all videos programatically.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm not quite familiar with Javascript yet, what does it mean to 'hook' into the page events, code-wise I mean?

Comment: Hooking into something = binding an event in jQuery.  Take a look at the example under the **Page show/hide events** heading.  The event you'll want to use is probably *pagebeforeshow*.

Answer (score 1):

Give the video an ID. Then...

$("a").click(function(){
    $("#videoID").pause();
});